# How can I allow system popup for location permission in Appium?

Tags: java, appium

[image: UI Automator viewer]I have tried few things to click on "OK" button for location permission Popup on Android:

1. With MobileBy.
2. With By locator.
3. By adding capabilities mentioned on other solutions.

But nothing is working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='button1']")).click();
```

Comment: can you share the element structure from UIAutomator..?

Comment: @akshaypatil added buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have shared the screenshot thank you for that can you please try the xpath

**Xpath:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='OK']")).click();
```

and let us know...^.^

Answer (score 3):

For your app you can click ok using:

```
driver.findElementById("android:id/button1").click();
```

> using xpath is not recommended in appium.

For android System permission pop up you can allow/deny permission by:

```
//to allow permission
driver.findElementById("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button").click();

//to deny permission
driver.findElementById("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_deny_button").click();
```

For ios system permission popup you can allow/deny permission by:

```
//to allow permission
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("OK").click();

//to deny permission
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Don’t Allow").click();
```

> You can also use add **autoGrantPermissions=true** (for android) and **autoAcceptAlerts=true** (for ios)  capability in your **DesiredCapabities**.

Comment: Tried both alternatives but not working, maybe I am doing something wrong. Thanks for your quick response